# Why didn't the atmosphere kill the aliens in Signs?

Tags: alien-invasion, signs

If the aliens in the movie *Signs* could be poisoned by

> water,

why didn't the atmosphere kill them? Why would it have to be in liquid form?

Comment: I got the impression that water burned them (much like acid would), not that it poisoned them.

Comment: Oh, don't even get me started on this plot hole. ;)

Comment: I can't compete with @Thaddeus's answer, but it was observed by one of the characters that none of the ships/signs occurred near water. Living near the Mississippi, I can verify that near the water, there is more moisture in the air. (yeah, I know, duh, common knowledge...) I got the impression that the aliens chose to attack further from water for this very reason. Likely moisture in the air *did* affect them, but they were able to tolerate it better where there was less of it.

Comment: It always amazed me (as a UK SF fan) to encounter an SF plot that lacked anoraks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anorak_(slang)

Comment: @gnovice On the other hand, [the same could almost be said of us humans...](http://i0.wp.com/lolzombie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/windchill.png)

Comment: They burned like how Zim burns in Invader Zim when exposed to water, they could have invaded earth easily if they followed Zim's example and bathed in paste

Comment: Always wondered why they even bothered to invade a planet covered in water if it's dangerous to them. At least the aliens in Alien Nation didn't have a choice in the matter.

Comment: Why would aliens decide to colonize a planet that is mostly water? Also they seemingly walked around naked as if there is no dew. It is indeed a ridiculous plot hole

Comment: Perhaps the aliens were in such dire straits that they had no choice but to invade a world like ours. Would have been nice to have that outlined, though.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but isn't this title a major spoiler?

Comment: The film version of Day of the Triffids was resolved in a similar way, only it was salt water that did the trick. When I first saw the Signs ending, I wondered at such a blatant rip-off.

Comment: Actually there's a conspiracy theory that the aliens are actually demons and the water is actually holy water. I personally support the conspiracy theory.

Comment: The subject of this question is one of the aspects in which the *Signs* rip-off [*Silent Warnings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Warnings) makes more sense than the original.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The aliens in this movie were not poisoned, per se by water. They instead acted as if they had been burned by a strong acid. Water vapor may have a similar effect but only if they are exposed to it long term. Depending on the water density in the atmosphere, it may act mostly as an irritant in the short term.

Water COULD function as an acid, but it requires a number of conditions to be met. It is a rather simplistic idea that, because the pH of water is 7, it is "neutral." It isn't.

- Water has 2 lone pairs of electrons on the oxygen, one of which can be donated to a suitable acceptor. Water is therefore a [Lewis base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases).
- Water also contains hydrogens, which under suitable conditions can be donated as protons. Therefore, water is a potential [Bronsted-Lowry acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%B8nsted%E2%80%93Lowry_acid%E2%80%93base_theory).
- In many environments, it will act as neither. But in the right environment, with suitable reagents, it can act as either

**Explaining this without invoking acidity/basicity:**

- 2H2O (l) <-----> H3O+(aq) + OH-(aq)

**In the presence of strong hydrides, water acts as an acid:**

- NH2- + H2O <-----> NH3 + OH-

**In the presence of strong acids, water acts as a base:**

- HCl + H2O <-----> Cl- + H3O+

Water can act as either an acid or a base, dependent on the circumstances.

Comment: Just a point of fact, you say water is a Lewis *base* but I believe it is also a Lewis *acid*...

Comment: It has the rare distinction of being both. You are correct!

Comment: (Aliens get -1 for attacking a species that's 90% lethal acid, on a planet covered by over 70% lethal acid, where lethal acid randomly falls from the sky, and there's been repeated fiction about how stupid a water-vulnerable alien would have to be to come here.  You Fail Tactics Forever.)

Comment: Great analysis. Actually I wish they were poisoned by it as soon as they arrived, that way the movie would have never happened and I wouldn't have to be bothered by this gigantic plot hole!

Comment: There is a quote in the movie where a news caster makes a statement that China had found a primitive way to fight the Aliens... I always pictured a bunch of guys running around with squirt-guns...

Comment: So if the aliens were for some reason mainly hydrides (perhaps their skin had high amounts of hydrides?) water would act as an acid on their skin?

Comment: @DoctorWho22: It would act pretty much like acid on your skin does. The concentration is important. For example, there are lots of medicine products like anti-wart stuff that includes hydrochloric acid. It won't eat all your skin because the concentration is low enough. But with the concentration being high enough... ouch. Same for them, just with water.

Comment: It's also possible that they aren't actually burned by acid but rather soluble in it. If I made a little igloo out of sugar cubes, it wouldn't spontaneously melt because of humidity, but it would if I poured a glass of water on it.

Comment: It's no more stupid than War of the Worlds where the aliens study Earth for a million years yet don't bother to invent antibiotics

Comment: Hard to see microbes through a telescope.

Comment: @Oldcat Not when you have already sent tech to the planet. We are already looking for microbes on Mars with a few poxy rovers

Comment: Hey, even we tried to do calculations in feet instead of meters and mess stuff up... whose to say the alien in charge of that department wasn't the brightest crayon in the box either? (No offense to the guy that did that... I would have too more than likely...)

Answer (score 1):

### The aliens were killed by *belief*

The movie isn't an alien invasion movie; it's a movie about faith and redemption. It's the story of the lost and angry ex-Father Graham Hess' road to forgiveness and regaining the strength to be a father, brother and preacher and, most importantly, to accepting his wife's death and forgiving her killer.

The aliens are an allegory for Graham's demons and they may not even be objectively real.

**It isn't that water harms them, it's Graham's belief that the water harms them that harms them.**

Comment: There was also a comment on the radio just before the final "swing Meryl, swing" that the vulnerability to water was "first discovered somewhere in the Middle East, in the early hours of the morning."  To me, this has always suggested that God transformed the water into a harmful substance to help repel the aliens ("Holy water" if you will.). I'm no Bible-thumper or anything, but I agree that you can't just ignore the religious aspects of the story.  This movie isn't *just* science fiction.

Comment: Well Merrill saw them, alone independently, without Graham, so they for sure were real.

Comment: I don't think he had a grudge per say against Ray. I think he knew Ray didn't kill her on purpose. His grudge was against God for allowing it to happen.