# Why would the aliens in Signs come to a planet that's mostly poison to them?

Tags: aliens, signs

Water is toxic to the aliens in the movie Signs. My question, short as it maybe is: **why would they come to a planet full of the one thing that is sure death?**

The reason they came was to steal our resources, but most of our consumable resources are made of water.

Comment: How do you know they came to steal our resources?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The aliens in the movie Signs end up poisoned by... water?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22503/the-aliens-in-the-movie-signs-end-up-poisoned-by-water)

Comment: Well, most of the surface of the Earth is sure death to us too.

Comment: Because it was a stupid, stupid movie. They can travel to Earth, but end up locked in some guy's pantry? (The guy is the **horrible** director's cameo, no less.)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This question is about the alien's motivation, not about the plausbility/implausability of water being deadly to them.

Comment: Agreed with @Zibbobz. Related, but not a dupe.

Comment: @JackBNimble... the kid said one the reasons they would come is because they exhausted their resorces

Comment: It's heavily implied that they are demons and the water is holy water.

Comment: @cde... what evidence do you have to suport this other than he is an ex-priest

Comment: “most of our consumable resources are made of water” — is oil made of water?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite... by consumable i meant edible, our plants and animals. Also though oil os not a waterbased substance it does originate by the heating and compression or organic mater i.e. plants and animal, oil may not be made out of water it is made of things that at one poin consisted of water therefore on their planet would not exist and they would not know what to do with it or have a need for it

Comment: First of all I don't think water is what killed the aliens. Otherwise there would have been many fatalities on part of the alien forces and/or the invasion would have been ended. It just doesn't add up. Aliens in a crop field at night with moisture in the air and from the dew of the crops, and they seem perfectly fine. And to respond to the pantry door. The door was BOARDED UP. It takes time to bust out of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Because mining rare elements is often dangerous**

As noted, sentient life is rather rare in the universe (that we can tell) - and while it is hard to determine exactly what the aliens were after, they seem to at least be after humans themselves.  From the [Aliens Wiki](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_%28Signs%29):

> Although the reason for the alien's attack has never been officially stated, a survivor heard on the radio in the basement states that they came to harvest humans. He backs this up by stating that he and his friend saw the aliens poison his friend's family and drag away the bodies.

The aliens actually seem very specifically suited for quietly invading a planet like Earth and carrying away people.  They can camouflage, poison their prey and drag them away.  Why they seem to be so dedicated to abduction isn't clear, but assuming we are valuable enough to make an interstellar trip, hide out in corn fields and kidnap us seems to indicate we're pretty valuable *somehow*.  It's plausible they need something specific from us that is unique to humans (genetic material perhaps).

Regardless, if we are that valuable it must be worth the risk to enter a possibly hazardous environment.  This isn't particularly surprising - we have many examples where gathering a valuable material is done at great risk (coal mining probably being the most classic example).

Answer (score 5):

I would venture to guess that the low probability of finding a planet that supports life and that is somewhat compatible enough to support the aliens themselves would play a role in it. So rather than they made a poor choice, perhaps they were looking for any port in a storm, so to speak.

Here's a quick read about the [Drake Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation) and could possibly give some insight on what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

It could not have been the water. It just doesn't add up. There's water moisture in the dew of the crops at night, and aliens were heard in the crops in one scene, and they didn't seem to be in danger. Plus the aliens were probably on earth for a long time, at least a few months, it had to have rained quite a few times.
It might have been something in Bo's tap water, no the water itself.

Comment: If this is really an answer, and not just a comment on the question, then you need to give some *evidence* (not just "it had to have rained quite a few times") that the aliens were not vulnerable to poisoning from water.  There are parts of the US where, depending on the season, a month without rain is not unheard of.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the Hydrophilic Aliens came to harvest humans as slave labor and came in for a quick grab. Unaware of the composition of the human body being mostly water the people they harvested were toxic to them. Humans in real life would fight to the death before anyone took them off planet which was one thing not accounted for.  How the Aliens didn't get burned by dew, rain, or other sources of water is a huge mistake in the story.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have a source for the fact that they wanted to harvest humans as slaves?  And why is that enough to brave the dangers of a planet where toxic liquids fall from the sky?